# Injecting current time into date script

Tags: javascript

I have a datepicker that is used to set the date of a reservation.  However, the output simply gives MM/DD/YYYY but the REST API requires MM/DD/YYYYThh:mm:ssZ (honestly not sure what the "T" and "Z" are for, but that's how the documentation has it written).

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    var today = new Date();
    var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
    var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

    today = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;


    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: nonWorkingDates,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        minDate: today,
        maxDate: '+2M',
        firstDay: 0
    });

    function nonWorkingDates(date){
        var day = date.getDay(), Sunday = 0, Monday = 1, Tuesday = 2, Wednesday = 3, Thursday = 4, Friday = 5, Saturday = 6;
        var closedDates = [[7, 4, 2019]];
        var closedDays = [[Sunday]];
        for (var i = 0; i < closedDays.length; i++) {
            if (day == closedDays[i][0]) {
                return [false];
            }

        }

        for (i = 0; i < closedDates.length; i++) {
            if (date.getMonth() == closedDates[i][0] - 1 &&
            date.getDate() == closedDates[i][1] &&
            date.getFullYear() == closedDates[i][2]) {
                return [false];
            }
        }

        return [true];
    }
});</script>
```

Since the reservation date will be set by the selected date, the time seems irrelevant to me, but it appears that the code requires it.  So, is there a way to inject the timestamp into the date variable so that it would appear like (using an example) "2019-05-08T18:05:58.435Z"

Comment: Not sure about the T and the Z? [Check out this Wikipedia article, it's right at the top](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Use date method `toISOString()` as follows

```
var d = new Date();
d.toISOString() // "2019-08-03T05:06:47.249Z"
```